# Slope and euclidean geometry (grade 10)

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given Triangle $DEF$ with vertices $$D(-2,6),E(7,3), \text{ and } F (2,-3)$$ find:

a) the equation of the altitude from vertex $E$ in standard form (include y=mx+b)

b) Find where this altitude in a) intersects side $DF.$

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: I am completely lost and I have no idea on what to do. Thanks.

Comment: please help and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

i will give you some hints.

(a) can you find the slope of $DF?$

(b) let $P$ be the foot of the perpendicular from $E$ to $DF.$ what is the relation between the slopes of $EP$ and $DF?$

(c)  you know the slope of $EP$ and the point $E=(7,3).$  can you write the equation of $EP?$

(d) can you also write the equation of the $DF?$

(e) can you solve the two simultaneous equations in $(c)$ and $(d)?$

Comment: Okay so I got 4x-9y+9=0 or y=4/9+3/2 which is ALMOST correct. The correct answer would be 4x+9y+1=0. I can't find where I went wrong. Thanks :D

Comment: @as,  i will modify the hint $c.$ check that out.

Comment: i think i found it; I had to find slope DF, then perpendicular passing through (7,3). Next, I had to use linear systems to find point of intersection. thanks a lot.

Comment: @as, you are welcome.